# mysql automatic replication of partial data

Tags: mysql

I have to create a dashboard based on a table in mysql, and only on today datas
This db is used on a service with a massive data quantity, and continous read and write data, so I'd like to replicate in a "slave" instance  part of this table (only today data).
Is it possible to do it in Mysql, without scripting?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to access todays data today? Or do you mean you want yesterdays data to be available

Comment: You could use a view and filter only today date. `your_column_date = current_date()` or  `your_column_date = now()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want see todays data today.
The Db is a based of a PBX solution, and I'd like to show data about some KPIs based on today calls

Comment: @ErgestBasha well, It could be, but I'd like to avoid to do continous query on the main DB (the dashboard will have a refresh every X seconds) in order to avoid extra load, that's why I was wondering to use a "slave replica"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has no built-in feature to replicate a subset of rows. There are replication filters to replicate a subset of schemas or tables, but not rows.

One workaround could be to replicate fully to the replica, then on the replica delete any data that is more than one day old.

But this would work only for a database that is INSERT-only. If you also have UPDATE and DELETE operations replicated, they might find that they are trying to change rows that are missing. If you use ROW-based binary logs, this would result in a replication error when it can't find the row, and replication would stop.

It might work if you only use STATEMENT-based binary logs, but I've never tried it so I can't predict what other problems might occur. Also, you can't fully prevent ROW-based binary logs from occurring, because individual sessions can change their binary log format.

I think you're going to need a bespoke solution no matter what. Probably not using replication, but just an ETL job to query the current day's data and import it into another MySQL instance (not a replica).